# 2nd Anniversary Party

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Some of you may have seen *[We're coming up on our anniversary, how should we mark the auspicious event?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1877/were-coming-up-on-our-anniversary-how-should-we-mark-the-auspicious-event)* and the resulting *[1st Year Anniversary Party](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1885/1st-year-anniversary-party)* and so we're thinking that we should give it another go. So, now it's time to start this rolling!

So, here's what we're going to do... If you have any funny or heartwarming pet stories, photographs, anecdotes, or events to share then this is the place. As Tim mentioned in the linked post, our friends at Stack Exchange will have some swag for participants and the rules are really simple:

- Must be about your own pets (past or present)
- Please ***no down votes*** as we want this to be positive
- Post as often as you like, each answer should be self-contained
- Winner will be selected ***Oct 8th*** based on ***total up votes*** (down votes will be discarded)
- In the event of a tie, oldest post will win (for being a keener)

Main prize, of course, is everlasting Pet's glory for having the best story for our anniversary. May even be special swag, but we'll need to check with our Community Manager friends first.

Comment: Was swag ever sent for last year's? I don't remember ever receiving it if so, but...lets just say my brain isn't always the most reliable thing.

Comment: Also I am really excited to see what kind of awesome posts we get this year, last year it was super fun!

Comment: This will be awesome opportunity for owners to show off their pets!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little late in the sequence, but...

A couple of months ago, the last of our cats, Junior, passed away and so we'd been petless since then. We had resolved to not get another cat for about 6 months, but the will is weak. :) We just returned from vacation yesterday and the house was empty, and felt it, and so we realized that our self-imposed time limit was going to collapse. So, without further ado...

## Betsy

Betsy is a climber, loves high places, including your shoulders. She was the first to make it clear that we belonged to her.

[image: Betsy]

## Blueberry

The inquisitive little explorer. We adopted her despite some known allergy issues, it's something we can handle and she's quite affectionate.

[image: Blueberry]

## Hobbes

Hobbes is a petting sponge. A little timid in the new digs, but when he settles in, I'm pretty sure that he will find laps to hang out on.

[image: Hobbes]

The ladies at the Humane Society told us that we had made their weekend. :D

Comment: You brought home 3 adult cats from the Humane Society at the same time?  Super Cool!

Comment: @JamesJenkins - We did! We only intended two, but fate intervened to include Blueberry in the mix.

Comment: Congratulations on the new additions to your family!

Answer (score 4):

A few years ago I adopted two adult cats who didn't previously know each other.  I had no idea how well they would ultimately get along, but I was hopeful.

I was careful to make sure I had one doughnut-bed per cat.  I have yet to see both of them in use at the same time.  Instead, this is pretty typical:

[image: Giovanni and Orlando]

I'll call that an integration win. :-)

The gray one on the left is Giovanni, and the brown tabby on the right is Orlando.

Answer (score 2):

Fall leaves are potato chips for Rabbits.

[image]

Note: the house rabbits in this photo are supervised, penned (xpen) and treated for fleas. Related [How accurate does the 30 day span when applying revolution flea treatment need to be?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/8194)

Comment: I think you're going to need more rabbits if you want to keep up with the falling leaves. ;)

Comment: Cool!  I had no idea rabbits liked post-green leaves.  Who's in the picture?

Comment: These are all rescue rabbits the we adopted. Harmony is the black rabbit.  Lyra is white, and Baxter is the Brown Dutch this picture was taken a couple of years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby is a rescue rabbit who has been through some tough times, she is a 5 year old English Spot.  Her two favorite things are eating and getting pets.  We often take her out for educational events. Here she is at one of her favorites [Angora Gardenes Autumnfest](http://www.angoragardens.org/) were she spent hours eating fresh grass and letting kids pet her.

[image: Ruby With Kids at Event]

The blue thing is her harness, with leash attached.